# Uploading pictures to a folder using PHP

Tags: php, html, file-upload

So I am trying to follow this tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) but I am having a hard time getting it to work the way it is supposed to. So I made a file called `fileToUpload` and in this file I have four files. First, `php.ini` with the following code:

```
file_uploads = On
```

Second, `upload.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Third, `upload.php`:

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
?>
```

And lastly, I have a folder called `uploads`, with nothing inside that folder. I should note that the `upload.html`, `upload.php`, and `php.ini` are all in a folder called, `fileToUpload`.

Now, when I click the submit button, it shows the code that is inside of `upload.php` with nothing inside the `uploads` folder. But, it is supposed to get the uploaded file into the `uploads` folder. However, it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the call that placed the uploaded file in that directory. Something down the lines of (shamelessly copied from the tutorial you linked to):

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. After your reading your answer, I decided to copy and paste the `Complete Upload File PHP Script` into my `.php` file but still, after I click the submit button, it just displays the code...

Comment: @JaeKim Does your webserver have PHP installed? Is it configured to handle `.php` files?

Comment: I'm actually not doing it through like a webhosting site. I'm just doing it locally on my computer... Is that the problem?

Comment: I should upload files to fireftp that's like linked with my webhosting that handles the PHP files?

Comment: But the thing is the PHP code works. Like `echo` and declaring arrays and loops and such.

Comment: @JaeKim hosting isn't the issue - web **serving** is the issue. PHP is a server-side language. When you access a PHP file, the code runs on the server side (which has to have PHP installed and configured, of course), and serves  a (typically HTML) response to the browser. You could install httpd and run it locally, or use some free hosting.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh okay. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file it does not go straight to where you want but to a temporary folder deifined by your server's configuration.
Then you have to move the temporary file to where you want it.

```
move_uploaded_file ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] , $target_file );
```

AND php must have the right to write on the destination folder